# Spring @ResponseBody produces an invalid JSON for primitive types

Tags: json, spring, rest, jackson

I have a code from a REST API which uses `@ResponseBody` to return the result, and a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` to return it in a JSON format.

It all works well for complex objects.
For primitives like `int`, `boolean` and `string` I get a JSON which does not start with { or [.
This is not a valid JSON.

I was wondering what is the proper way to return just a simple type like that?
Should I encapsulate it in an object such as `{ Result : true }` ?

Thanks

Code sample:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/login",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public boolean Login(String username, String password) {
    return authenticationService.authenticate(username, password);
}
```

This will return just `true` or `false` which is an invalid JSON. It should either be encapsulated in an object or an array (if I understand correctly).

Answer (score 8):

It does just return true, or false. And you are correct that is not json.

It can't be json because its not an object, it is simply a primitive, so its fine as is - it will be assigned to a javascript variable in your success handler.

If you return a list of Booleans you get an array :

```
[true,false,true]
```

If you must have fully formed json don't return a primitive use a hashmap or custom wrapper object.

```
public
@ResponseBody
Map<String, Boolean> getTrue() {
  Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>(1){{put("result", Boolean.TRUE);}};
  return map;
}
```

Returning a hashmap is probably the simplest and best way to get the json you require :

```
{"result":true}
```

Comment: The problem is that there are things which expect a correct JSON. For example the Flex Builder tool which encapsulates REST API calls in Flex expects the results to be in JSON.

Comment: stick the data in a custom wrapper object or a hashmap

Answer (score 4):

I've found convenient to use

```
public class ObjWrapper<T> implements Serializable {

  private T obj;

  public ObjWrapper(T obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  public T getObj() {
    return obj;
  }

}
```

then in controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/getString") @ResponseBody
public ObjWrapper<String> getString() { ...
```

and on client (jquery)

```
$.getJson("getString", {}, function (data) {
            alert(data.obj);
          })
```

same with lists:

```
public class ListWrapper<T> implements Serializable {

  private List<T> content;

  public ListWrapper(T... objects) {
    content = Arrays.asList(objects);
  }

  public ListWrapper(List<T> content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  public List<T> getContent() {
    return content;
  }

}
```